# VIM: simple steps to create syntax highlight file - for logfiles

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have some (log4j generated) logfiles to go through; I know their format pretty well (I mean I have already got off-the-peg regexes etc I can use).

I want to automatically highlight them in VIM when I load them up (*.log).

A logfile entry looks something like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSS [...] #LOG-LEVEL# [...] Message
```

Where #LOG-LEVEL# is one of the standard 'ERROR', 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'FATAL'....and the 'YYYY-MM...' represents the date/time to millisecond resolution.

To get me started , what are the steps needed to get the date-string highlighted in (say) yellow-background with blue text - and also when the  text reads ' ERROR ' this should have a red-background with white text.

I have tried going through some tutorials on this, but can't find one which is simple enough to understand, so I'm after some real basic steps here !

Cheers

EDIT:
Here's the summary of what I did, based on the instructions below:

1. Created the syntax file 'log.vim' in .vim\syntax (see below for example content).
2. Created a file in .vim\ftdetect\log.vim with the following content:

   au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log     set filetype=log
3. Made sure the following are in my startup settings:

   syntax on
   filetype on

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are three ways of defining syntax items (see `:help :syn-define`):

- Keywords: these are for items that are simple strings of keyword characters.  This is the fastest matcher.
- Matches: these are regular expressions for matching.
- Regions: these are for long regions that are likely to contain other items.

There are various arguments that make things more complicated (to do with matches within regions etc), see `:help :syn-arguments` for a discussion of this.

There is a priority that comes into effect (see `:help :syn-priority`).

Colouring is controlled by the highlight command and is separate to the syntax commands.

A simple way to get started would be to use a match to detect the date and a keyword to detect error.  Then use highlight to make the colours come to life:

```
" This creates a keyword ERROR and puts it in the highlight group called logError
:syn keyword logError ERROR
" This creates a match on the date and puts in the highlight group called logDate.  The
" nextgroup and skipwhite makes vim look for logTime after the match
:syn match logDate /^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/ nextgroup=logTime skipwhite

" This creates a match on the time (but only if it follows the date)
:syn match logTime /\d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}/

" Now make them appear:
" Link just links logError to the colouring for error
hi link logError Error
" Def means default colour - colourschemes can override
hi def logDate guibg=yellow guifg=blue
hi def logTime guibg=green guifg=white
```

Bung all of that in ~/.vim/syntax/log.vim and make sure the file type is set properly (see `:help filetype.txt`) - it should then load automatically.

Hopefully that should give you something to get going with.  Have a (very gradual) read of the various sections of `:help syntax.txt` and `:help usr_44.txt` for further info.

Comment: great stuff - works a treat (even if it the time field is shown as a yucky eye-searing white on light-green ;-) ) Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Sorry, I just picked some random colours without testing.  That would be a pretty nasty colour combination!

Comment: nah - no worse than my choice of yellow/blue ! (I think Mode 7 on BBC Micro had too much of a lasting effect on me ;-)

Cheers - works great - got the file match working as well now - nice one.

Answer (score 10):

You can start from

```
syn match group1 /^\d\+-\d\+-\d\+/ nextgroup=group2 skipwhite
syn match group2 /....../ nextgroup=group3 contained skipwhite
syn match group3 /....../ nextgroup=group4 contained skipwhite

hi link group1 Comment
hi link group2 Conditional
hi link group3 Identifier
```

and then just continue to experiment

Comment: Thanks - that's a good start. +1
Assuming I want this automatic when I load '*.log': where do I put this (syntax\log.vim I think?) - and do I need any extra bits in my startup ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Log4jHighlighter](https://github.com/codelibra/log4jhighlighter). The installation details are present on github.

Comment: When I try to change the extension on **.xlog** - it works, but when on **.log** it doesn't. What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: The mistake was in my **.vimrc**, sorry

Answer (score 1):

To load automatically with *.log files you should make an [ftplugin](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html) for  this filetype.

For example, in my `log.vim` file in my `.vim/ftplugin` folder I have simple instructions for setting a keyboard shortcut when loading *.log files.

**Note**: ftplugins may not be the best way to do this... setting the syntax file as [Al](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193157/vim-simple-steps-to-create-syntax-highlight-file-for-logfiles/2193282#2193282) describes is probably better.  I'll leave this answer here though for the alternative possibility.

Comment: Thanks for that - in fact used the other method, which was to create a file '.vim\ftdetect\log.vim' with contents "au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log  set filetype=lo" to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This highlighting style works just great for me:

https://github.com/dzeban/vim-log-syntax

The author (@AlexanderDzyoba) says it is based on "messages" syntax highlighting file.