# Ending syntax region at the start of a given pattern

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, logging

This is a follow-up from [VIM: simple steps to create syntax highlight file - for logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193157/vim-simple-steps-to-create-syntax-highlight-file-for-logfiles)

I am trying to use the 'region-match' facility to syntax-highlight stack-traces in some logfiles: these logfiles (log4j-based) look a bit like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSSS...INFO...Message
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSSS...INFO...Message
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSSS...ERROR...Message
...stack trace...
...stack trace...
...blah blah, more server-vomit...
...
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSSS...INFO...Message
```

So far I have managed to almost do what I want with this:

```
:syntax region error matchgroup=string start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}.* ERROR/    end=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}/
```

But the issue, is that match goes too far. It includes the next record (ie, the match includes the next `YYYY-MM-DD...`).

I believe this [VIM manual example for quoted text](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-excludenl) suggests that I should be able to highlight in-between, but I don't seem to be able to map the syntax for my example.

So to be clear: I need to match the first `YYYY-MM-DD...` line that includes `ERROR`, and then all subsequent lines *up to but **not** including* the next `YYYY-MM-DD` line.

Comment: Solution with regions looks a little bit ugly. This '^' start symbol at the end is like a hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of difficulties with overlapping regions in Vim's syntax highlighting engine.  The order in which matches and regions are defined makes a difference and it can be very hard to make it do what you want.

The main thing I'd suggest is to look at `:help syn-pattern-offset`.  This provides a means to make the region end at the start of a pattern among other things.  For example if your end pattern is:

```
end=/pattern/re=s-1
```

Then the region will end at the character before the `p` of pattern.

This takes a lot of playing around to make it work and I'm far from being an expert on these things, but to get you started, try this:

```
syntax match logDate /^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/ containedin=logDateTimeTypeLine nextgroup=logTime skipwhite
syntax match logTime /\d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}/ containedin=logDateTimeTypeLine,logTrace
syntax match logDateTimeTypeLine /^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}.*/
syntax region logTrace matchgroup=logErrorStartLine start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}.*ERROR.*/ms=s,rs=e+1 end=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}/me=s-1,he=s-1,re=s-1
hi link logTrace Error
hi link logDateTimeTypeLine Keyword
hi link logDate String
hi link logTime Comment
hi logErrorStartLine guifg=red
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:help keepend

:syntax region error matchgroup=string start=/.../ end=/.../ keepend
```

Comment: Thanks - had tried that in fact - it does (almost) do what I want - but it seems to force the start and end patterns to go pink !(Because of "string" I think) : tips on how to get round that ?

Comment: OK - I have it working as I want by using 'matchgroup=normal' [not sure this is optimum solution, but it works exactly right for me].

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work either...the first pattern is also 'de-highlighted' - its only the terminating pattern which I need to be excluded from the highlight - possibly I'm stretching a mechanism that wasn't really designed for logfiles - more for languages that tend to have matching pairs of 'bookends'...
+1 stays, but had to take off 'accepted answer' I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

My file is an adaptation :-)
here it is:

```
syntax region fatal start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*FATAL.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1
syntax region error start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*ERROR.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1
syntax region warn start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*WARN.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1
syntax region info start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*INFO.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1
syntax region debug start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*DEBUG.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1
syntax region trace start=/^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}.*TRACE.*/ end=/\n\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/me=s-1,re=s-1

" Highlight colors for log levels.
hi fatal ctermfg=DarkRed ctermbg=Black
hi error ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Black
hi warn ctermfg=Magenta ctermbg=Black
hi info ctermfg=Green ctermbg=Black
hi debug ctermfg=LightCyan ctermbg=Black
hi trace ctermfg=LightMagenta ctermbg=Black
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell Vim to use a positive lookahead [using the `\@=` construct](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/@=). With a lookahead, you can match the text on the next line *without including or consuming it.* Use the same `start`, but change your `end` to:

```js
/\(^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}\)\@=/
```

Note that this is incompatible with Vi.