# Custom syntax highlighting in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

how to highlight strings that begin with `sql_` and are inside quotes?

My Logfile:

```
MGPostgreSQLConnection.OpenQuery; "sql_p_factory_history"-ExecTime: 47ms
2010-11-12T17:28:18+01:00;custom; MGPostgreSQLConnection.OpenQuery; "sql_p_factory_history"-ExecTime+FetchTime: 47ms
2010-11-12T17:28:18+01:00;custom; MGPostgreSQLConnection.OpenQuery; "sql_factory"-ExecTime: 47ms
2010-11-12T17:28:18+01:00;custom; MGPostgreSQLConnection.OpenQuery; "sql_factory_contactperson"-ExecTime+FetchTime: 62ms
```

My vimrc (This doesn't work, of course):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log syn match "sql_*"
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log hi sql guifg=white guibg=red
```

Answer (score 7):

You were nearly there! This version (works and) doesn't highlight the quotation marks.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log hi sql guifg=white guibg=red ctermfg=white ctermbg=red
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log syn match sql /"\zssql_\w*\ze"/
```

[image: screen-shot]

See the following for more information:

- `:help :syn-match` " for syntax matching, erm, syntax
- `:help /\zs` " sets the start of the match there
- `:help /\ze` " sets the end of the match there
- `:help /\w` " word character

---

**Debugging:**

The command `:verbose :syn` should give you something like this:

```
--- Syntax items ---
[...]
sql            xxx match /"\zssql_\w*\ze"/
```

And `:verbose :hi`:

```
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
[...]
sql            xxx cterm=bold ctermfg=7 ctermbg=1 guifg=white guibg=red
```

The `xxx` should be in the same colours as you have specified (and look like the highlighting in my screen-shot). If you don't see those, check that your `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` on Windows) is sourced:

```
:scriptnames
1: /home/javh/.vimrc
[...]
```

Of course this only works when:

```
:echo has('syntax')
```

...returns `1` (or `:version` includes `+syntax`).

Comment: that `\zs` and `\ze` is good if you want not to highlight the guillemots. But I think that the `[^"]*` is a bit too permissive.

Comment: Thanks for help. Your solutions doesn't work for me, but maybe points me in the right direction.

Comment: "Doesn't work", how? I've just tested it and uploaded a screen-shot.

Comment: I believe you, even without your screenshot. I do not know why it does not work for me.

Comment: If you update your question with details of your OS, which version of Vim and any errors you are getting I'll try to help.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu and Win7 with Vim 7.2, but on XP with Vim 7.3 not.

Comment: Glad it's working for you on a couple of installations. Do any of the debugging steps above help you with v7.3 on XP?

Comment: The results of the debug steps are OK (as described by you).

Comment: If the 'xxx' string appears in the correct colours then you must be able to display them. Is the log file exactly the same? (Not using "smart quotes" or similar)? Perhaps try a different match pattern...

Comment: @JAVH: Did you try a different match pattern?

Comment: This works, but the quotes are also marked (7.3): syn match sql /"sql_\w*"/

Comment: The only reason I can think of for `\zs` and `\ze` not working is that you don't have the `+syntax` feature enabled on that installation. But that wouldn't be right. Would it? `"{not in Vi} {not available when compiled without the |+syntax| feature"`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `syn match`  is `syn match highlight_group reg_exp`.

So, try :

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.log syn match Todo /"sql_\w\+"/
```

Why don't you read the help for `:syn`? Vim help is so good that you find all answers fast :)

```
:help :syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this thread? [VIM: simple steps to create syntax highlight file - for logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193157/vim-simple-steps-to-create-syntax-highlight-file-for-logfiles)

Comment: Thank you, but I need a special "syn match".

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, without `syntax match`, is to use the `:match` command or the `matchadd()` command directly.

In brief:

```
" to enable
:match Todo /"\@<=sql_\w\+"\@=/
" reference:
" \@<= is such a beautiful duck, :help /\@<= for more help
" :help /\@= for the \@= part, also.
"
" to cancel
:match none
" :help :match / :help :2match / :help :3match
```

or

```
" to enable
:call matchadd('Todo', '"\zssql_\w\+\ze"')
" or
:let foobarbaz = matchadd('Todo', '"\zssql_\w\+\ze"')
"
" to disable
:call matchdelete(foobarbaz)
" or
:call clearmatches()
```